# GitLab Pages with GitLab Omnibus in Docker + naked Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, gitlab

I'm hosting a GitLab EE instance (v11.9.0) in a Docker container (Omnibus installation) and have an Apache reverse proxy (not in Docker) in front of it to handle SSL. Now I would like to serve static pages for some projects using the GitLab Pages functionality, which turns out to be a bit tricky with the Docker setup.

I'm following [this official guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/#dns-configuration) to achieve that my pages are served under `http://namespace.customdomain.com/projectname`. I added the wildcard DNS records and tinkered with the `gitlab.rb`; these are the relevant changes:

```
pages_external_url "http://customdomain.com/"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['external_http'] = ['0.0.0.0:81']
gitlab_pages['inplace_chroot'] = true
pages_nginx['enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['pages_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages"
```

(Some of the changes above don't go in line with the instructions from the guide, I know. But those didn't work either, so I went ahead and tried around a lot, this is just the current status.)

Port 81 is mapped to port 9081 of the host machine and the Apache has a virtual host entry to pass traffic there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.customdomain.com

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:9081/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9081/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I used the `.gitlab-ci.yml` in an example project to produce a simple website, which is just an `index.html` with `hello world` in it. This file is correctly put at `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages/[namespace]/[project]/public/index.html`.

At `[Project]/Settings/Pages`, GitLab tells me:  "Congratulations! Your pages are served under: `http://namespace.customdomain.com/project`" .

If I now try to visit the page under `http://namespace.customdomain.com/project`, I get GitLab's 404 error page.

The good thing here is that I am therefore pretty sure that handing traffic to the pages daemon works correctly – if I stop the pages daemon with `gitlab-ctl stop gitlab-pages`, the 404 page disappears and I get a proxy error from Apache. The bad thing is that serving pages still doesn't work as expected.

Has anybody managed to serve GitLab pages using a similar setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. Just add `ProxyPreserveHost on` in the Apache config and everything works nicely. I cannot provide any details about why this did the trick, maybe somebody more experienced with Apache can give some insights.

The full vHost configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAlias *.customdomain.com

    <Location />       
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass http://localhost:9081/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9081/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I‘ve tried to troubleshoot this for 4 hours. Thanks fir sharing your solution!